# Android NDK - static libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, библиотеки, android-ndk

Какие `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` вообще существуют?
Почему, когда мне нужна библиотека cpufeatures, я должен в Android.mk прописывать так:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cpufeatures
....
$(call import-module,cpufeatures)
```

и

```
#include <cpu-features.h>
```

А когда нужно библиотека `unistd.h`, то хватает только этого:

`#include <unistd.h>`

Нужно ли `unistd.h` прописывать в `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` также? Может, если я ее не пропишу туда, то будет лишняя нагрузка на систему. Я, возможно, бред пишу, объясните, плиз.

Вот почему эти 2 библиотеки отличаются (их оформлением) и какие вообще существуют статические библиотеки? Где смотреть?

Comment: @Andreyua, я могу ошибаться, пусть поправят меня более опытные товарищи. Дело в том, что unistd входит в стандартную библиотеку разработки. Тем не менее, на Android эта стандартная библиотека имеет собственную реализацию, отличную от Linux реализации, и имеет название Bionic. Погуглите просто информацию, что в неё входит, а что - нет, и будете точно знать, как правильно подключать.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/system/Os.html#sysconf%28int%29

:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Библиотеки в с/с++ бывают двух видов - "header only" (то есть только заголовочные файлы, то есть .h) и библиотеки, которые нужно линковать.

Примером header only может быть библиотека, где определены константы и маленькие функции (вида min/max) прям в самом .h файле. Такие библиотеки нужно только подключать с помощью include - они уже все нужное содержат.

Второй тип содержит код, который был предварительно скомпилирован и упакован в специальную библиотеку (в линуксе/андроиде это .a файлы, в видновсе - .lib). И вот для подобных библиотек нужно линковщику указать, где искать реализацию функций и классов, так как в .h обычно определен только интерфейс. Если линковщик не знает, где взять реализацию, то он не может собрать результирующий бинарник.

[unistd.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/unistd.h.html) содержит в себе определение констант и заголовки к функциям, которые компилятор и линковщик знает где взять. Поэтому ничего подключать и не нужно. Все уже известно.

> Может если я ее не пропишу туда, то будет лишня нагрузка на на систему.

Нет, не будет.

> Вот почему эти 2 библиотеки отличаются (их оформлением), и какие вообще существуют статические библиотеки.

Выше я уже описал. Но библиотеки, которым нужна линковка, делятся на две категории - статической линковки (это .a которые) и динамической линковки (.so для линукса и .dll для винды). В случае статической линковки код "вставляется" в результирующий бинарник, в случае динамической линковки - нет, но нужны внешние файлы (те самые .so/.dll). Некоторые библиотеки могут быть в двух форматах, некоторые только в каком-то одном (я сходу так не придумаю явных причин, которые бы запрещали их делать сразу в двух форматах, обычно это зависит от разработчика библиотеки).

> Где смотреть?

Тип библиотеки и как ее правильно подключить, обычно описывается в read.me файлах. Либо гуглится. Либо, используя седьмое чувство, подключается самостоятельно.